# How to implement the interface at the database level (Symfony3, Doctrine ORM, SonataAdminBundle)?

Tags: symfony, oop, doctrine-orm, orm, sonata-admin

I'm using Symfony 3, Doctrine ORM and SonataAdminBundle.

There is a task, that can be solved by the implementation of some interface on code level, but I don't know how to properly store the data of such a structure in the database and edit these data in the admin panel.

Suppose there are such initial conditions.

There is a "Film" doctrine entity. The table `film` in the database.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="film")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Film
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

There is a "User" doctrine entity. The table `user` in the database.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

There is a "Cinema" doctrine entity. The table `cinema` in the database.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="cinema")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Cinema
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Town
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Town")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="town_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $town;

    /**
     * @return Town
     */
    public function getTown()
    {
        return $this->town;
    }

    ...
}
```

As we can see, the "Cinema" has a "town" field, which determines in which town the cinema is located. So there is also a "Town" doctrine entity. The table `town` in the database.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="town")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Town
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

Next, it becomes necessary to create from these data a "log of views", i.e. store the data about each view in the entity "View" (nothing to do with the view of MVC). The table `view` in the database.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="view")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class View
{
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var Film
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Film")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="film_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $film;

    /**
     * @var Cinema
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cinema")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cinema_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $cinema;

    /**
     * @return Cinema
     */
    public function getCinema()
    {
        return $this->cinema;
    }

    ...
}
```

A quite simple scheme.

Suppose that in our business logic it is very important, in which town the user has watched the film. To find a town we cat do this: $view->getCinema()->getTown(), and get the needed "Town" object.

But suddenly it turns out that the user could watch the film not only in the cinema, but also:
- on TV;
- by computer.

At the code level, the solution seems extremely simple: declaring the "ViewPlaceInterface" that has the getTown() method and implementing this interface in "Cinema", "TV", "Computer" classes.

```
interface ViewPlaceInterface
{
    /**
     * @return Town
     */
    public function getTown();
}

class View
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var ViewPlaceInterface
     */
    private $viewPlace;

    /**
     * @return ViewPlaceInterface
     */
    public function getViewPlace()
    {
        return $this->viewPlace;
    }

    ...
}

class Cinema implements ViewPlaceInterface
{
    /**
     * @return Town
     */
    public function getTown()
    {
        ...
    }
}

class TV implements ViewPlaceInterface
{
    /**
     * @return Town
     */
    public function getTown()
    {
        ...
    }
}

class Computer implements ViewPlaceInterface
{
    /**
     * @return Town
     */
    public function getTown()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This allows us to call $view->getViewPlace()->getTown() and get the "Town" object.

My question: How to implement this in Symfony 3, Doctrine ORM, SonataAdminBundle? What tables and entities should be created? How should the doctrine ORM be configured? How to configure the sonata-admin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, if i understand your question in right way, the best solution will be to use [table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

More examples: [first](https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2012/03/27/table-inheritance-with-doctrine.html), [second](https://medium.com/@jasperkuperus/defining-discriminator-maps-at-child-level-in-doctrine-2-1cd2ded95ffb)